# Merge the tags search-engine and search-engines

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retag-request, meta

... to leave only [search-engines](/questions/tagged/search-engines), since plural tags are preferable. Currently, both [search-engine](/questions/tagged/search-engine) and [search-engines](/questions/tagged/search-engines) exist.